# CNAME dropping URL parameters?

Tags: dns

I am having the following problem, and I believe the issue is with my CNAME, but I'm not sure. I have a cname record set to send www.mydomain.com to mydomain.com. However, the following is happening:

www.mydomain.com/page.ext?test=1 -> mydomain.com/page.ext

It's rolling over to be without the w's, but losing the URL parameters.

What is the typical solution to this problem, if any?

Comment: That's not a CNAME.  CNAMEs do not redirect.  You're seeing an HTTP issue.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

That's not a CNAME.
A CNAME is simply an alias to the IP address of a different domain name; it has nothing to do with redirection.

You're seeing an HTTP issue.

Comment: But what is the solution to this problem?

Comment: @JomarSevillejo: Check your server configuration.

Comment: Right. The behavior was correlated, but not related. The problem isn't in the CNAME, it's somewhere on the server itself.